# Fetching tsrange that ends between now and the end of the day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a Rails app, I'm using PostgreSQL as the database.

The model `reservation` has the `tsrange` attribute `reserved_between`.

I'm tried to fetch all the reservations than end between now (`Time.zone.now`) and the end of the day (`Time.zone.now.end_of_day`) but I'm having a hard time doing so.

Any ideas how I can get those reservations?

Comment: `Reservation.where(%q(upper(reserved_between) BETWEEN :now AND :end),
                                        now: Time.zone.now,
                                        end: Time.zone.now.end_of_day)`
seems to work for me.